# Passing vector to function

Tags: c++, vector

While trying to clean up my code a bit I ran into a problem that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to pass vector values to a function so that I can do the evaluation in a function rather than in the main code, but I can't figure out how to actually pass the vector correctly.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int population_size = 10;
int number_of_variables = 3;

struct one_individual
{
std::vector<std::vector<double>>chromosomes;
double evaluation1 = 0;
double evaluation2 = 0;
double evaluation3 = 0;
double fitness = 0;
double probability = 0;
};

std::vector<one_individual> individuals;

double evaluation(std::vector<one_individual> individuals[i])
{
individuals[i].evaluation1 = 1 * individuals[i].chromosomes[0].at(0) + 2 * individuals[i].chromosomes[0].at(1) + 3 * individuals[i].chromosomes[0].at(2);
individuals[i].evaluation2 = 1.5 * individuals[i].chromosomes[0].at(0) + 3 * individuals[i].chromosomes[0].at(1) + 4.5 * individuals[i].chromosomes[0].at(2);
individuals[i].evaluation3 = 2 * individuals[i].chromosomes[0].at(0) + 4 * individuals[i].chromosomes[0].at(1) + 6 * individuals[i].chromosomes[0].at(2);

individuals[i].fitness = 1 / (individuals[i].evaluation1 + individuals[i].evaluation2 + individuals[i].evaluation3);

return individuals[i].fitness;
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());    // random-number engine (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-10.0, 10.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
    {
        std::vector<double>variables;
        for (int j = 0; j < number_of_variables; j++)
        {
            variables.push_back(dist(rng));
        }
        individuals[i].chromosomes.push_back(variables);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
    {
        evaluation(individuals[i]);
        std::cout << "Individual " << i << " has fitness of " << individuals[i].fitness;
    }       
}
```

I've tried to condense the code as much as possible so that it's not too much to read, I think everything still in there does need to actually be in there.

Anyway, the ways I've tried to pass on the values of the vector to the function all aren't working and the answers I could find sadly don't clear up my mistake for me.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by saying ` pass the vector correctly`?

Comment: `double evaluation(std::vector<one_individual> individuals[i])` should be changed to `double evaluation(std::vector<one_individual> individuals)` if that's your intent. I would avoid passing by value using a reference instead...

Comment: @Gmichael, right now the code won't compile so I would say I'm not passing the vector on to the function correctly. What I would like to happen is for the "chromosomes" to be passed on to the function so that the calculations can happen inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through the vector and process one element at a time, you just have to pass the type that is being iterated over

```
double evaluation(one_individual& person)
{
    // do stuff with person
}
```

To iterate over your vector you would do something like

```
for (auto& person : individuals)
{
    evaluation(person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double evaluation(std::vector<one_individual> individuals[i])
```

should be

```
double evaluation(std::vector<one_individual>& individuals)
```

Also get rid of the global variable with identical name as your parameter. There is no reason to declare it as global in the first place.

Comment: Good point about the global. But this answer won't work as is, without the OP passing in an index `i` or - probably best - refactoring to work on a single element at a time as indicated by Cory.

Comment: @underscore_d I answered how to pass the vector to a function. How to change the OP's code so that it makes any sense is another matter.